# How to extract specific value from a string with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, visual-studio

I am new to Regex and i want to extract a specific value from a string, i have strings like:

```
"20098: Blue Quest"
"95: Internal Comp"
"33: ICE"
```

and so on.Every string has the same pattern : Number followed by ":" followed by a space and random text. I want to get the numbers at the start for ex: `"20098","95","33" etc.`

i tried

```
Regex ex = new regex(@"[0-9]+\: [a-zA-Z]$")
```

This is not giving me any solution, Where am i going wrong?
(i am using c#)

Comment: Could you give more details about what you mean by "This is not giving me any solution"? You've only shown the declaration of a regular expression, not any use of it. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you. Note that currently your regular expression only allows for a single character after the number and colon though... Also note that if you want to extract a value from a regular expression, you may well want to look into *capturing groups*.

Comment: If the strings are always in this format, you do not need regex, you may use `s.Split(':').FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Thank you this is easy to understand!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, after colon, yoiu should use \s instead of literal space. Also, if the text after colon can include spaces, the second group should also allow /s and have a + after it.

```
[0-9]+\:\s[a-zA-Z\s]+$
```

Secondly, that entire regex will return the entire string. If you only want the first number, then the regex would be simply:

```
[0-9]+
```

Comment: But there could be numbers in the text after the colon, will the regex be [0-9]+\: ? as i want the numbers before the colon

Comment: If they want only the numbers from the beginning then they should anchor it with `^`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a totally silly solution. However, i decided to benchmark an unchecked pointer version, against the other regex and int parse solutions here in the answers.

You mentioned the strings are **always** the same format, so i decided to see how fast we could get it.

**Yehaa**

```
public unsafe static int? FindInt(string val)
{
   var result = 0;
   fixed (char* p = val)
   {
      for (var i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
      {
         if (*p == ':')return result;
         result = result * 10 + *p - 48;
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

I run each test 50 times with 100,000 comparisons, and 1,000,000 respectively with both Lee Gunn's `int.parse`,The fourth bird version `^\d+(?=: [A-Z])` also my pointer version and `^\d+`

**Results**

```
Test Framework : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Scale : 100000
Name                   |       Time |      Delta |  Deviation |       Cycles
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pointers               |   2.597 ms |   0.144 ms |       0.19 |    8,836,015
Int.Parse              |  17.111 ms |   1.009 ms |       2.91 |   57,167,918
Regex ^\d+             |  85.564 ms |  10.957 ms |       6.14 |  290,724,120
Regex ^\d+(?=: [A-Z])  |  98.912 ms |   1.508 ms |       7.16 |  336,716,453


Scale : 1000000
Name                   |        Time |      Delta |  Deviation |         Cycles
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pointers               |   25.968 ms |   1.150 ms |       1.15 |     88,395,856
Int.Parse              |  143.382 ms |   2.536 ms |       2.62 |    487,929,382
Regex ^\d+             |  847.109 ms |  14.375 ms |      21.92 |  2,880,964,856
Regex ^\d+(?=: [A-Z])  |  950.591 ms |   6.281 ms |      20.38 |  3,235,489,411
```

Not surprisingly regex sucks

Comment: wow this is nice

Comment: Ha - I like it! Handy approach to know if perf is ever an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If they are all separate strings - you don't need to use a regex, you can simply use:

```
var s = "20098: Blue Quest";

var index = s.IndexOf(':');
if(index > 0){
    if(int.TryParse(s.Substring(0, index), out var number))
    {
     // Do stuff   
    }
}
```

If they're all contained in one sting, you can loop over each line and perform the `Substring`. Perhaps a bit easier to read as a lot of people aren't comfortable with regular expressions.

Comment: On the other hand, it won't validate that the text is in the expected format - it will silently return strings in some broken cases (e.g. "foo:bar") and throw an exception if there's no colon. With a regular expression, it's easy to express the pattern you expect the text to follow, check that it *does* do that, and then extract the part you want.

Comment: I added some basic checks

Comment: Except that allows negative numbers (we don't know if they're valid or not) and requires that the number is in the range of `int`. (It also doesn't check for a space after the colon.) We don't know whether those are valid assumptions or not... and by the time you've added those checks, it's as long-winded as the regular expression version, but less precise. While I agree that there are times when a regular expression isn't the most appropriate approach, from the information we've got so far in the question, I'd use one.

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `"[0-9]+: [a-zA-Z]$` you match one or more digits followed by a colon and then a single lower or uppercase character.
That would match `20098: B` and would not match the digits only.

There are better alternatives besides using a regex like as suggested, but you might match from the beginning of the string `^` one or more digits `\d+`  and use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what follows is a colon, whitespace and an uppercase character `[A-Z])`

[`^\d+(?=: [A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/hrwtvR/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use look-behind `?<=` to find any number following `^"` (where `^` is the beginning of line):

[`(?<=^")[0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/VwdODg/1)

Comment: I think the double quotes are to indicate they are string literals and are not actually part of the string being processed.